# Jquery datepicker years change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using datepicker of jquery for a field to set date of birth, while default picker is displayed which gives option to scroll to date monthly and sounds tedious. Is there a way by which I can change years directly rather using months to change the year in turn.

Comment: You are using the default jQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There's a `changeYear` property on the datepicker that you can set to `true`.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ changeYear: true });
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

This will render a select list from which you can choose the year you'd like.

Comment: what is I don't want a *select*, but a small *input* ? keeping all styles, and functionality

Answer (score 26):

Insert `changeYear: true` on your DataPicker parameter.

Example :

```
$(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Set `changeYear: true`, as shown in sample code below:

```
 $("#birth_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: '-1D'
        },
        $.datepicker.regional["fr"]
    );
```

Refer here for more options: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 6):

`changeYear` property lets you enable a year [dropdown](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear). Also might be helpful to use `yearRange` property to control [number of years](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) they see in the dropdown, by default it's from -10 to +10 years.

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-40:+40"
});
```

Details from original documentation:

> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year ("-nn:+nn"), relative to the currently selected year ("c-nn:c+nn"), absolute ("nnnn:nnnn"), or combinations of these formats ("nnnn:-nn"). Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the minDate and/or maxDate options.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a year dropdown by using the 'changeYear' property (see: [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)) from the datepicker object.