# Datepicker using angularjs is working fine but not able to change year directly

Tags: angularjs

**Datepicker in my application is working fine but i am not able to change year directly. I have to go month by month to change year**

Directive for datepicker

```
app.directive('adatepicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      $(el).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In HTML page

```
 <input type="text" adatepicker="" ng-model="Date"/>
```

screenshot of datepicker

[image: datepicker]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388923/jquery-datepicker-years-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear), initialize the datepicker with the changeYear option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  changeYear: true
});
```

Get or set the changeYear option, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var changeYear = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "changeYear" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "changeYear", true );
```

Comment: $(el).datepicker({ changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {...}});

Comment: now i got the solution but one problem in dropdown the year values are not visible.

Comment: that might have something to do with the css.

Comment: ya that was css problem i got solution for that thanks